# Reshape 2D dataframe to include previous data points (for LSTM in Keras)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a dataframe with 100000 samples and 10 features. I want to convert this to a 3D array where [X][0] is the current data point, [X][1] is the previous data point (X-1) etc. So if i want a "lookback" of five units, the shape of the data would look like (100000, 5, 10). The reason being that i want my LSTM to consider previous data points when training the model.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe is of shape (100000, 10), you cannot reshape it to a (100000, 5, 10), simply because you don't have 100000x5x10 values in it. So, the first step is to create the lagged features:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[i for i in range(5)], 'b':[i for i in range(5, 10)]})
> df
>       a   b
    0   0   5
    1   1   6
    2   2   7
    3   3   8
    4   4   9
> columns = [df.shift(i) for i in range()]
> df = pd.concat(columns, axis=1)
> df
>       a   b   a   b   a   b
    0   0   5   NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   1   6   0.0 5.0 NaN NaN
    2   2   7   1.0 6.0 0.0 5.0
    3   3   8   2.0 7.0 1.0 6.0
    4   4   9   3.0 8.0 2.0 7.0
```

After this, you can reshape your dataframe to suit your needs:

```
> # 5 samples, 3 timesteps, 2 features
> df.values.reshape(5,3,2)
> array([[[ 0.,  5.],
    [nan, nan],
    [nan, nan]],

   [[ 1.,  6.],
    [ 0.,  5.],
    [nan, nan]],
  ...
```